# SSO with Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) 4.x

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I'm trying to set up Single Sign-On for my customer between their on-premises AD  and Salesforce (Sales Cloud). They are using ADFS 4.x. We followed SF [instructions that were written for ADFS 3.x](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_examples_3p_adfs.htm) but it is not working at all. To be honest, I am not sure about the whole test process either. Where do I start looking?

[image: Validator Error]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you've linked to applies to ADFS 2.0 no ADFS 3.0 or 4.0 although it might possibly work since the SAML 2.0 standard is still valid. There's a troubleshooting article for ADFS 2.0 here: [Diagnostics in AD FS 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/card/diagnostics-in-ad-fs-2-0) which might be helpful to you as referenced in the link you provided.

The fact the SAML assertion validator tool isn't able to parse the response (end of file) suggests some kind of basic configuration error that's perhaps related to something like whatever you're using for the FederationID being case sensitive or something else you've set in your basic set-up for matching between active directory fields and Salesforce fields. It could also be a discrepancy in the encryption protocol but I'd expect something like that to prevent you from making a connection at all.

This is probably where you need to log-in to the Salesforce instance directly to make certain the user you're testing has valid data that matches what's in the LDAP server along with your SAML settings.